# Java: running test at compilation time or at application execution

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

First of all I am not good at testing. I have an OSGI CRUD application. And I want to make tests for auto testing business logic. And I see here two options:

1. run tests at compilation time - at certain maven phase
2. make tests as separate bundle and run it after starting the application. For example, if I click somewhere at main menu.

Which one is the right choice? Or both are possible?

The reasons why I am asking this questions are the following:

1. I've never seen option 2, but seen a lot of option 1.
2. Option 2 is for me a better one, because business logic includes working with database, index system and memory cache and I've got not idea how to check it during compilation time.

Comment: for option 2 (which sounds like functional testing) you might like to look at Selenium / Webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, option 1 is not a compile time testing. Maven run the test before install/deploy the bundle after compile your code.

Option 1 is for Unit testing. In detail, before install or deploy any bundle, need to make sure each and every unit of your code working as expected.

Option 2 is for functionality testing. Test begins by invoking or testing the main gateway or main functionality, that will invoke the multiple modules internally. Based on the input, some of the unit may execute or may not..  primary focus of this testing is to cover and make sure the different scenario of the functionality.

Good developer should do both. Hope this helps!!